# HTML not rendering inside Razor if

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have inside a view file something like

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.RuleId }) |                     
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.RuleId }) |
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RuleId })
```

and this works, but when I change it to something like

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.RuleId }) |

     @if( something )
  {                
  Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.RuleId });
  Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RuleId });
  }
```

it stops displaying the second and third items ( although is entering the branch ) .

Any ideas why ?

Comment: `<text>@Html.ActionLink(derp)</text>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` returns an `IHtmlString` object containing an `<a>` tag.
It doesn't do anything by itself.

Your code is ignoring this result, so nothing happens.

You need to print the result to the page using the `@` character.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. But still I don't understand why do I need the `@` character inside the if statement. Isn't it sufficient that the if statement has it ? I thought the `@` was just to delimit a Razor block of code.

Comment: @coredump: `@` in Razor means two different things.  `@{` or `@if` opens a code block (what you're talking about).  `@expression` prints the expression to the page (what I'm talking about) and can appear in code or markup contexts.

Comment: Ok. I thought that the `@expression` was a o shorthand for on line of code. I suggest you might add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.RuleId }) |

@if( something )
{                
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.RuleId })
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RuleId })
}
```